# Change parskip in eledmac

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, parskip, eledmac

When I try to adjust `parskip` in `eledmac`, it only takes effect when the paragraph starts with a `label`.

For example:

```
%!TEX TS-program =  xelatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\parskip=\baselineskip

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
\noindent \textsc{Dubitabit autem aliquis etc.} Consequenter quaeritur
circa istam partem ubi philosophus movet dubitationem circa motum
caeli. Movet ibi istam dubitationem utrum caelum dependeat ab aliquo
in motu suo. Ideo quaeritur utrum caelum in motu suo dependeat ab
aliquo corpore fixo et immobili.\pend

\pstart 
\emph{1.} Et arguitur quod non. 
\pend

\pstart 
Consequenter quaeritur circa istam partem ubi philosophus
movet dubitationem circa motum caeli. Movet ibi istam dubitationem
utrum caelum dependeat ab aliquo in motu suo. Ideo quaeritur utrum
caelum in motu suo dependeat ab aliquo corpore fixo et immobili.
\pend

\pstart
\label{test-label} Consequenter quaeritur circa istam partem ubi
philosophus movet dubitationem circa motum caeli. Movet ibi istam
dubitationem utrum caelum dependeat ab aliquo in motu suo. Ideo
quaeritur utrum caelum in motu suo dependeat ab aliquo corpore fixo et
immobili.  
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Gives this result.
[image]

Is this expected behavior? Any ideas?

Comment: Note `scrartcl` has the `parskip=on` option for making such a setting, however the output still has the same strange spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more the default behavior of eledmac which change when a edlabel begin a pstart than a bug. Nore ledmac, nore eledmac were conceptualized to add this parskip (it is lost when the splitting process is made) and just the  `\edlabel`/`\label` called at the begining insert it by mistake (you could prevent it by adding `\leavevmode` before).

So the solution will be to use `\cs{AtEveryPend}` to insert it manually.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\parskip=\baselineskip
\AtEveryPend{\vskip\parskip}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
\noindent \textsc{Dubitabit autem aliquis etc.} Consequenter quaeritur
circa istam partem ubi philosophus movet dubitationem circa motum
caeli. Movet ibi istam dubitationem utrum caelum dependeat ab aliquo
in motu suo. Ideo quaeritur utrum caelum in motu suo dependeat ab
aliquo corpore fixo et immobili.\pend

\pstart 
\emph{1.} Et arguitur quod non. 
\pend

\pstart 
\strut Consequenter quaeritur circa istam partem ubi philosophus
movet dubitationem circa motum caeli. Movet ibi istam dubitationem
utrum caelum dependeat ab aliquo in motu suo. Ideo quaeritur utrum
caelum in motu suo dependeat ab aliquo corpore fixo et immobili.
\pend

\pstart
\leavevmode\label{test-label} Consequenter quaeritur circa istam partem ubi
philosophus movet dubitationem circa motum caeli. Movet ibi istam
dubitationem utrum caelum dependeat ab aliquo in motu suo. Ideo
quaeritur utrum caelum in motu suo dependeat ab aliquo corpore fixo et
immobili.  
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

You could also open an issue on github to ask for such option.

Comment: you'r welcome. But please open an issue, I think many people could ask for it ;-)

Comment: I don't understand what this issue should request. Is there any reason to make a specific feature for changing `\parskip` when I can just use the `\AtEveryPend`?

Comment: it's more about handbook, to prevent people ask again.